# Split a collection of objects based on a condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects to be added in a bag and bags capacity is 100 qty

The Object and Bag look like below

```
public class MyObject{
    String id;
    int qty;
}

public class MyBag{
    String id;
    int qty;
}
```

Is there any way to split MyObject in multiple MyBags grouping on the qty limit using Java 8 streams

For example: myObjects are

```
[myObject1:{id1, 150}, 
 myObject2:{id2, 30}, 
 myObject3:{id3, 150}]
```

Since bag has a capacity of 100.
Bags should be grouped as

```
[ bag1:[{id1, 100}], 
  bag2:[{id1, 50},{id2, 30},{id3, 20}], 
  bag3:[{id3, 100}], 
  bag4:[{id3, 30}]]
```

Comment: What is the difference if I store 75 id1 and 25Id2 in Bag1 and 25Id2 and 75Id1 in Bag1? or 76Id1 and 26Id2? What algorithm decides which bags can store a maximum of what count etc. Is there some rule of thumb? a threshold or a logic?

Comment: To do the above
You need to create a list inside the MyBag class.
As there's no difference between the classes right now.

Comment: No, Java streams won't provide an easy solution to this problem. You'll have to code it.

Comment: So your objects have their own individual quantity, and are added to a bag, which has a maximum quantity of 100? So you effectively want to sort the objects into bags that add up to 100?

Comment: Use imperative programming for this task, this is not really a use case for streams

Comment: @omoshiroiii yes.

Comment: @JBNizet Alright then, I was thinking if there was an out of box solution for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was maintained in comments the solution won't be easy. Below is an example that is close to what you want. First I used only first class `MyObject` and change it a bit.

```java
public class MyObject{
    String id;
    int qty;

    public MyObject(String id, int qty) {
        this.id = id;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", qty=" + qty +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Init code:

```java
List<MyObject> myObjects = Arrays.asList(
        new MyObject("id1", 150),
        new MyObject("id2", 30),
        new MyObject("id3", 150)
);
```

And the main code. In `flatMap` there is splitting `MyObject` with large `qty`. After that objects are collected to lists with given limit. The output isn't exactly as you want. The third list includes two objects with identifier `id3`.

```
[MyObject{id='id1', qty=100}]
[MyObject{id='id1', qty=50}, MyObject{id='id2', qty=30}, MyObject{id='id3', qty=20}]
[MyObject{id='id3', qty=80}, MyObject{id='id3', qty=20}]
[MyObject{id='id3', qty=30}]
```

```java
LinkedList<List<MyObject>> firstCollection = myObjects.stream()
    .flatMap(o -> o.qty < 100 ? Stream.of(o) : IntStream.range(0, (o.qty / 100 + 1))
        .mapToObj(x -> new MyObject(o.id, x < o.qty / 100 ? 100 : o.qty % 100))
    )
    .collect(
        Collector.of(
            LinkedList::new,
            (a, b) -> Optional.of(a).filter(Predicate.not(List::isEmpty))
                    .map(l -> l.getLast().stream().map(o -> o.qty).reduce(Integer::sum).get())
                    .filter(lastSum -> lastSum < 100)
                    .ifPresentOrElse(lastSum -> {
                        int maxQty = 100 - lastSum;
                        if (maxQty >= b.qty) {
                            a.getLast().add(b);
                        } else {
                            a.getLast().add(new MyObject(b.id, maxQty));
                            a.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(new MyObject(b.id, b.qty - maxQty))));
                        }
                    }, () -> a.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(b))))
            ,
            (a, b) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
        )
    );
firstCollection.forEach(System.out::println);
```