# How to split an integer to a list of many dividers and its remainder

Tags: java, collections, java-8, initialization, java-stream

I want to create collection (or immediately `Stream`), that for given integer creates collection containing its n dividers and remainder. Below is simple code that creates this:

```java
int initValue = 151;
int chanckValue = 50;

List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
int value = initValue;
while (value > chanckValue) {
    ints.add(chanckValue);
    value = value - chanckValue;
}
ints.add(value);

System.out.println(ints);
```

And output is:

```
[50, 50, 50, 1]
```

How can it be done ideal with `Stream`? Preferably in a compact way.

#### UPDATE

This is only example of usage. Multiplication in second map can be replaced with any operation:

```java
Stream.of(3, 54, 150, 151, 230)
.map(value -> {
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    while (value > chanckValue) {
        ints.add(chanckValue);
        value = value - chanckValue;
    }
    ints.add(value);
    return ints;
})
.map(l -> l.stream()
        .map(v -> v * v)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You don't need streams here. What you have is good enough. Just keep it.

Comment: I agree with other. in addition declaring `value` is redundant I think

Comment: Instead of streams you could instead use the knowledge that `151 / 50 = 3` and `151 % 50 = 1`. Your argument of "I need streams because I'm using streams later" is invalid, because you don't need streams later either. There are plenty of places where streams are *useful*, you don't need to cram them into all the places where they're not very useful.

Comment: Your 50 as a divisor/factor in 151 is a guess... do you expect stream of prime factors or any factors?

Comment: What is the purpose of your code please, what you want to achieve

Comment: @YCF_L I wonder is any more readable way of creating such collection.

Comment: @lczapski what are you trying to do with that code? You have a stream pipeline that prints out numbers, we're all wondering: **why**?

Comment: @Kayaman  As I was writing it before it is only for theoretical reason. I needed similar code when answering on other question. Where I needed to turn integer to such collection. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59729413/11733759

Comment: If you're more interested in "clever programming tricks" than "professional software development", I suggest you look into https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is no sense in performing unnecessary operations, even in a theoretical question. As said by @Kayaman, just doing `int q = initValue/chanckValue, r = initValue%chanckValue;` provides all relevant results. Looping, streaming, or creating a collection out of it adds nothing to it. But if you insist on creating a stream out of it... `IntStream is = IntStream.range(0, q).map(x -> chanckValue); if(r != 0) is = IntStream.concat(is, IntStream.of(r));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize information from comments. As [Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731549/how-to-split-an-integer-to-a-list-of-many-dividers-and-its-remainder/59738597#comment105612571_59731549) pointed out: `151 / 50 = 3` and `151 % 50 = 1` and [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731549/how-to-split-an-integer-to-a-list-of-many-dividers-and-its-remainder/59738597#comment105624728_59731549) provide an example of implementation:

```java
int q = value/chanckValue, r = value%chanckValue;
IntStream is = IntStream.range(0, q).map(x -> chanckValue);
if(r != 0) is = IntStream.concat(is, IntStream.of(r));
```

Other approach with `List`

```java
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(value / chanckValue, chanckValue));
if (value % chanckValue != 0) ints.add(value % chanckValue);
```

Or with postpone `ArrayList` creation if there are need to add remainder.

```java
List<Integer> ints = Collections.nCopies(value / chanckValue, chanckValue);
if(value % chanckValue != 0) { 
  ints = new ArrayList<>(ints); 
  ints.add(value % chanckValue); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursion with stream using `Stream.flatMap` and `Stream.concat`

```
public static Stream<Integer> chunkval(int val, int chanckValue) {
        if (val > chanckValue)
            return Stream.concat(Stream.of(chanckValue), chunkval(val - chanckValue, chanckValue));
        return Stream.of(val);
    }
```

then call the above method like this

```
Stream.of(3, 54, 150, 151, 230).flatMap(v -> chunkval(v,chanckValue)).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Note [the documentation of `concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)): *Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowError.*